# Could you technically call the string[] anything in the main method?

Tags: java, syntax, header, args, main-method

The header for the `main` method is

```
public static void main (String[] args)
```

Could you technically replace "args" with anything you want? Also, why is the parameter an array?

Comment: *Could you technically replace "args" with anything you want?* Why don't you try? *Also, why is the parameter an array?* So you can pass multiple command-line arguments.

Comment: You can rename it with any proper Java identifier. For instance you can use `foo` but you can't name it `1array` since variable names can't start with numbers. We call it `args` as short for "arguments" which are passed when we run this code via `java YourClassWithMainMethod arg0 arg1 arg2`.

Comment: Yes you can rename it to whatever you want.  The type is an array because that is how it was implemented.  Each element in the array contains a token from the command line.

Comment: The signature is based on the [`main` function of C programs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean), whose declaration, generally speaking, is `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.  Java doesn’t need `argc` because its arrays have a length field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`args` is just a name for the argument in a method. You can rename it to whatever you want. The JVM doesn't need to know what the argument is *named*; only the *type*, `String[]`, is important.

dont break the start point of the app

```
 static void main(String[] whateverYouNeed)
```

Comment: Just to add on to this and address the second part of the question, it's an array because you can pass multiple args (quoted or separated by whitespace) eg `java main somearg someotherarg "some third arg"` will result in your `String[]` param being `{"somearg","someotherarg","some third arg"}`

Answer (score 1):

You can rename it to any proper Java identifier. The application needs to be able to accept multiple command-line arguments. It doesn't necessarily have to be an array, you can use `varargs` also.

```
 static void main(String... whateverYouNeed)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main method could be written as:

- public static void main (String[] args)
- public static void main (String args[])
- public static void main (String... args)

The parameter name *args* could be replaced with any valid Java identifier like *blah*, *programArgs*, and so on.  It's an array to accept any number of command line arguments.  For example:

- *java programName* has no command line arguments
- *java programName arg1 arg2* has 2 command line arguments